# sigma notation confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Can someone please explain to me what this sigma notation means in this formula. Im confused because there is no top number on the sigma and what does this sum mean on the bottom?
and also this is the formula for the multinomial theorem, what are the $k_m$ values supposed to represent?
$$(x_1+x_2+...+x_m)^n=\sum_{k_1+k_2+...+k_m=n}{n \choose k_1,k_2,...,k_m}\prod_{t=1}^mx_t^{k_t}$$

Comment: This is the multinomial theorem.

Comment: yes i know, but what does this sigma notation mean?

Comment: It means the sum over all partitions of the integer $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{k_1+k_2+...+k_m=n}$ means you're considering the sum over all elements of the following set $$\bigg\{(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_m):\sum_{i=1}^mk_i=n,0\leq k_i\leq n\bigg\}$$

Answer (score 1):

The $k_i$ are nonnegative integers whose sum is $n$.  $k_i$ is the exponent of $x_i$ in a typical term in the expansion of $(x_1+\dots+x_m)^n$  The sum is taken over all $m-$tuples $(k_1,\dots,k_m)$ such that $k_1+\cdots+k_m=n.$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an application:
$$(x_1+x_2+x_3)^4=\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=4}{4 \choose k_1,k_2,k_3}\prod_{t=1}^3x_t^{k_t}=\\
{4\choose 4,0,0}x_1^4x_2^0x_3^0+{4\choose 3,1,0}x_1^3x_2^1x_3^0+{4\choose 3,0,1}x_1^3x_2^0x_3^1+{4\choose 2,2,0}x_1^2x_2^2x_3^0+\\
{4\choose 2,1,1}x_1^2x_2^1x_3^1+{4\choose 2,0,2}x_1^2x_2^0x_3^2+{4\choose 1,3,0}x_1^1x_2^3x_3^0+{4\choose 1,2,1}x_1^1x_2^2x_3^1+\\
{4\choose 1,1,2}x_1^1x_2^1x_3^2+{4\choose 1,0,3}x_1^1x_2^0x_3^3+{4\choose 0,4,0}x_1^0x_2^4x_3^0+{4\choose 0,3,1}x_1^0x_2^3x_3^1+\\
{4\choose 0,2,2}x_1^0x_2^2x_3^2+{4\choose 0,1,3}x_1^0x_2^1x_3^3+{4\choose 0,0,4}x_1^0x_2^0x_3^4=\\
x_1^4 + 4 x_2 x_1^3 + 4 x_3 x_1^3 + 6 x_2^2 x_1^2 + \\
6 x_3^2 x_1^2 + 12 x_2 x_3 x_1^2 + 4 x_2^3 x_1 + 4 x_3^3 x_1 + \\
12 x_2 x_3^2 x_1 + 12 x_2^2 x_3 x_1 + x_2^4 + x_3^4 + \\
4 x_2 x_3^3 + 6 x_2^2 x_3^2 + 4 x_2^3 x_3,$$
Wikipedia [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20(x_1%2Bx_2%2Bx_3)%5E4).

Note: The order of terms differs. Also: ${4\choose 3,1,0}=\frac{4!}{3!1!0!}=4$.

Comment: May I just ask how you knew how to list out every possible 3 tuple for the multinomial coefficient?

Comment: see [Pascal's pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid).

Comment: absolutely wonderful! but here is another thing that is bugging me, how do i do that for a 4 tuple or 5 tuple or generally for an m tuple?

Comment: if $m=4, n=6$, then you should list them: $6000\\ 5100\\ 5010\\ 5001\\ 4200\\ \vdots \\ 0006$